# Adjust camera according to the scale

Tags: interface, camera

After i had adjusted my 3d objects to real world standards, my camera was really hard to control, it was moving way to fast. To be clear, i am not talking about the camera that is an object inside of blender, but the camera you use to view your scene, to change objects,

I have 2 questions
How can i adjust the interface camera to the scale im using it for?
What do you call the thing i was reffering to here as 'Interface camera'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the navigation for some reason gets weird in 3d viewport you can usually select some object hit  <kbd>Numpad .</kbd>  to frame it in the viewport. The movement speed of navigation should adjust according to the scale of that object.

You can also adjust various settings like orbit sensitivity in the Preferences( <kbd>F4</kbd>  ->  <kbd>P</kbd> ), Navigation tab:

[image]

Note that you should not use ridiculous sizes like for example if you make your objects in sizes of kilometers while working with default unit of 1 meter you might start to get various problems in your scene like for example you would need to change viewport and camera clipping planes and you might eventually encounter 32bit float precision issues. Instead, set your scene unit scale to a value adequate to what you are working with:

[image]

So if the average object you work with is a few meters big, defaults are fine, if it's a few millimeters big, you might want to set the unit scale to 0.001, if you are making something like planetary system, and the distances are in hundreds of kilometers, you might want to set the scale to something like 100 000 or higher.

This scale setting is a multiplier for the actual stored values in Blender. So if you have a default cube that is 2x2x2 meters and set the Unit Scale to 0.001 the cube becomes 2x2x2 millimeters. The values remain the same and they are just displayed as another unit so you can avoid binary precision errors this way and all functionality like unit conversion in text inputs or in advanced numerical input for modal operators(when you hit  <kbd>Numpad *</kbd>  while in operation such as transform( <kbd>G</kbd> ) and then can type "5in" and it automatically gets converted to 0.127m) still works.